# Get last pressed keyboard key

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard-events, key-bindings

I'm trying to get the last pressed keyboard key, but since I'm working in a game, the code will be ran each tick.
I tried getchar() but it results in a crash/freeze, how can I acheive this ?

This will only be used on windows 7/8/10

Comment: Crash and not a lock up? `getchar` should pitch a tent, start a fire, and camp out until a key is pressed. It won't get the last one, but it will get the next one. Probably need something operating system-specific. I don't have a good answer, but edit your question and add your target OS.

Comment: Actually come to think of it, I do have an answer: Spin up a second thread and let it hang on `getchar`, storing the value for the other thread to read.

Comment: Nah, that one requires you to hit enter. This day I suck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up hooking dinput8.dll's OnKeyboardMessage function to grab the last key pressed, which worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function

```
#include conio.h
..............
..............
void input()
{
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        switch (_getch())
        {
        case 'q':
            dir = LEFT;
            break;
        case 'z':
            dir = UP;
            break;
        case 'd':
            dir = RIGHT;
            break;
        case 's':
            dir = DOWN;
            break;
        case 'x':
            gameover;
            break;
        default :
            break;

        }

    }
}
```

while dir is

> enum Direction{STOP=0,LEFT,RIGHT,UP,DOWN};

Comment: #include <conio.h>
:D

Comment: Bit of fun with `_getch`.  Try and exit the program with ctrl+c.

Comment: Tried this, it does nothing:
`DebugConsole();
if (_kbhit())
    printf("%i\r\n", _getch());`